# Junit 4 execution order vs Junit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I am seeing some unwanted behaviour using Junit 5.
I have the following structure:

```
website
    config
        BaseTest.java
    tests
        package a
            Test 1
            Test 2
        package b
            Test 3
            Test 4
```

`BaseTest` contains an `@BeforeAll` with some one-time setup and an `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` to setup and teardown some data before and after each test.
Each test extends from `BaseTest`.

The way I am used to with Junit 4 is that the `@BeforeAll` in `BaseTest` is only run once when executing all the tests in all the packages at once. However, with Junit 5 it seems that the `@BeforeAll` is repeated when a test from another package is run. To clarify, I get something like this:

```
BeforeAll
    BeforeEach
        Package 1 Test 1
    AfterEach
    BeforeEach
        Package 1 Test 2
    AfterEach
AfterAll
BeforeAll
    BeforeEach
        Package 2 Test 1
    AfterEach
    BeforeEach
        Package 2 Test 2
    AfterEach
AfterAll
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: That’s how it works in JUnit 4, too.

Comment: Not really, I used this setup many times in junit 4 without problems.

Comment: Then you must have not have verified the actual behavior. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by overriding the `BeforeAllCallback` and registering it with my `BaseTest` like so:

`JunitExtensions.class`

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class JunitExtensions implements BeforeAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        //Code that needs to be ran before all tests goes here
    }
}
```

`Basetest.java`

```
@ExtendWith(JunitExtensions.class)
public class BaseTest {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> The way I am used to with Junit 4 is that the `@BeforeAll` in `BaseTest`
>   is only run once when executing all the tests in all the packages at
>   once.

That is incorrect.

I recreated your example using JUnit 4 annotations, and the following is the result:

```
BeforeClass
    Before
        Package 1 Test 1
    After
    Before
        Package 1 Test 2
    After
AfterClass
BeforeClass
    Before
        Package 2 Test 1
    After
    Before
        Package 2 Test 2
    After
AfterClass
```

Thus, the behavior in question is identical in JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for support for suite-level callbacks. Unfortunately JUnit 5 does not yet have support for _suites_.

Comment: One option would be track whether the `@BeforeAll` method has already been executed and make it effectively a no-op in case it has (e.g., via a static boolean field, AtomicBoolean, etc.)

Comment: Another option would be to implement a `BeforeAllCallback` extension that tracks whether it has been invoked by storing a flag in the _root_ `ExtensionContext`.